# How to Integrate existing Hibernate ORM with Cassandra?

Tags: hibernate, cassandra, kundera

My existing application environment is springWS, Hibernate and Oracle DB. I got a POC work to route / persist data in Cassandra DB in case oracle is down. So that it won’t impact end users.

For the above scenario, which one I have to use Hector/Thrift/Datastax/Kundera?

P.S : I am very new to Cassandra and written stand-alone program using Kundera to persist data in Cassandra. Is it possible to reuse ORM entities (POJOs) for data persistence in Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

It's a perfect Kundera use case. If using hibernate with JPA. Then you just need to change persistence provider(KunderaPersistence) and few configurations for mapping to Cassandra node. Rest you should be good to go.

I suggest you to join http://groups.google.com/group/kundera-discuss/subscribe  for more on discussion

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thanks much for quick response. But we are not using JPA. In this case still can I use Kundera? Plz suggest.

Comment: Kundera is a JPA compliant object mapper. As per your comment   ``` "Is it possible to reuse ORM entities (POJOs) for data persistence in cassandra".``` I thought you looking for POJOs to be persisted in Cassandra!

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I have created new JPAs to use Kundera.